# How to create new column with all non-NA values from multiple other columns?

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, conditional-statements, na

I would like to create a column d, which includes all the non-NA values from the other columns.

I tried ifelse, but cannot figure out how to make it nested in the proper manner, so that the value in column c is included as well..
Perhaps something else than ifelse should be used?

Here is a "dummy" dataframe:

```
 a <- c(NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", "A", NA, NA)
 b <- c("D", "A", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
 c <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", NA)
 data <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

I would like the d column to look like this:

```
 data$d <- c("D", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", NA)
 View(data)
```

Comment: `data[!is.na(data)]`

Comment: This changes the order of the values.

Comment: do you need to keep rows with all NA? (i.e. last row of your data frame)

Comment: Yes. Rows all with NA should be included in column d. And the order of the values should be intact.

Comment: You can also try `data[cbind(1:nrow(data), max.col(!is.na(data)))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that should've just out in "" and not " " in NA cells.

And if the space is not avoidable use trimws on the column of the dataframe to remove them afterwards:

```
  data$d <- trimws(data$d)
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `pmax`

```
do.call(pmax, c(data, list(na.rm=TRUE)))
#[1] "D" "A" "C" "A" "B" "A" "C" NA
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(a, b, c, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bit ugly idea assuming that you only have one non-NA value in each row,

```
data$d <- apply(data, 1, function(i) ifelse(all(is.na(i)), NA, i[!is.na(i)]))
data
#     a    b    c    d
#1 <NA>    D <NA>    D
#2 <NA>    A <NA>    A
#3 <NA>    C <NA>    C
#4    A <NA> <NA>    A
#5    B <NA> <NA>    B
#6    A <NA> <NA>    A
#7 <NA> <NA>    C    C
#8 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: I can't currently test it but I think you can just use na.omit instead of the whole anonymous function

Comment: Hmm... I thought it would drop all rows with na but cant test it either at the moment

Comment: What I mean is to apply na.omit by row (using apply). If I'm not mistaken, you should get an NA if you try to select a non-NA value from only NAs (but not 100% sure)

Comment: Ahh ok ...yes that makes sense...I will test it in the morning

Answer (score 1):

I also found this workaround, but I'm not sure I like it:

```
data <- as.matrix(data)
data[is.na(data)] <- " "
data <- data.frame(data)
data$d <- with(data, paste0(a, b, c), na.rm=TRUE)
View(data)
```

Comment: This is not actually a bad way. You beat me to it by  few seconds.  You can simplify it to 2 lines though: `data[is.na(data)] <- ""; 
data$d <- with(data, paste0(a, b, c))`

Comment: Thanks. Actually it turns out, that it saves the "empty cells" as a space, which gave be as many factor levels in column d as there are rows :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a similar problem much later in time and thought I would provide a more generalizable solution using `dplyr` and `stringr`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- c(NA, NA, NA, "A", "B", "A", NA, NA)
b <- c("D", "A", "C", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
c <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "C", NA)
data <- data.frame(a, b, c)

data %>% 
  mutate_all(stringr::str_replace_na, replacement = "") %>% 
  mutate(d = stringr::str_c(a,b,c)) %>%
  mutate_all(stringr::str_replace, pattern = "^$", replacement = NA_character_)
#>      a    b    c    d
#> 1 <NA>    D <NA>    D
#> 2 <NA>    A <NA>    A
#> 3 <NA>    C <NA>    C
#> 4    A <NA> <NA>    A
#> 5    B <NA> <NA>    B
#> 6    A <NA> <NA>    A
#> 7 <NA> <NA>    C    C
#> 8 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>