# Using the unite function in R and removing duplicated values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I'm trying to use the `unite` function in R to concatenate values across columns, but also deduplicate the values. How can I accomplish this?

Here is the input data:

```
input <- tibble(
  id = c('aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'qq'),
  '2017' = c('tv', NA, NA, 'web'),
  '2018' = c('tv', 'web', NA, NA),
  '2019' = c(NA, 'web', 'book', 'tv')
)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  id    `2017` `2018` `2019`
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 aa    tv     tv     NA    
2 ss    NA     web    web    
3 dd    NA     NA     book  
4 qq    web    NA     tv
```

The desired output with the ALL column is:

```
> output
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  id    `2017` `2018` `2019` ALL   
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 aa    tv     tv     NA     tv    
2 ss    NA     web    web    web   
3 dd    NA     NA     book   book  
4 qq    web    NA     tv     web, tv
```

Comment: Using the unite function results in NAs and doesn't produce the desired output in the rightmost column, which is part of the reason I asked the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if deduplicating is possible with `unite`, however you can use `apply` row-wise.

```
input$ALL <- apply(input[-1], 1, function(x) toString(na.omit(unique(x))))
```

---

Or a `tidyverse` way could be using `pmap`

```
library(tidyverse)

input %>%
  mutate(ALL = pmap_chr(select(., -id), ~toString(unique(na.omit(c(...))))))

#  id    `2017` `2018` `2019` ALL    
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  
#1 aa    tv     tv     NA     tv     
#2 ss    NA     web    web    web    
#3 dd    NA     NA     book   book   
#4 qq    web    NA     tv     web, tv
```

Or getting the data in long format and then joining

```
input %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -id, values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(ALL = toString(unique(value))) %>%
  left_join(input)
```

Comment: On my actual dataset, I'm trying to replace `select(., -id)` with `select(2017, 2018, 2019)` but getting `Error in UseMethod("select_") : no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`. How can I select specific columns? Tried quoting, putting in a vector etc and can't get it to work

Comment: Nevermind seems like `select(input, \`2017\`, \`2018\`, \`2019\`)` works

Comment: Yes, you need to use backquotes to select columns with non-standard names.

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions exist here on SO, but since you are after a `unite` solution and I couldn't find any that specifically use `unite`, here we go:

Using `unite`

```
input %>% unite(ALL, -id, sep = ", ", remove = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE)
## A tibble: 4 x 5
#  id    ALL     `2017` `2018` `2019`
#  <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1 aa    tv      tv     NA     NA
#2 ss    web     NA     web    NA
#3 dd    book    NA     NA     book
#4 qq    web, tv web    NA     tv
```

To recover the exact column order of your expected output, you can add a `%>% select(names(input), ALL)`.

Alternatively, using `nest`

```
input %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    nest() %>%
    mutate(ALL = map_chr(data, ~toString(unlist(.x[!is.na(unlist(.x))])))) %>%
    unnest(data)
## A tibble: 4 x 5
## Groups:   id [4]
#  id    `2017` `2018` `2019` ALL
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1 aa    tv     NA     NA     tv
#2 ss    NA     web    NA     web
#3 dd    NA     NA     book   book
#4 qq    web    NA     tv     web, tv
```

Or the base R way (as in [How to create new column with all non-NA values from multiple other columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374971/how-to-create-new-column-with-all-non-na-values-from-multiple-other-columns)):

```
input$ALL <- apply(input[, -1], 1, function(x) toString(x[!is.na(x)]))
input
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#   id    `2017` `2018` `2019` ALL
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1 aa    tv     NA     NA     tv
#2 ss    NA     web    NA     web
#3 dd    NA     NA     book   book
#4 qq    web    NA     tv     web, tv
```